# How do I match the year with value for-loop in java?

Tags: java, loops

I am new to programming so please don't judge me. I am doing a project were, I add a score for each year. for the output it should say the highest score and which year it was in, but I don't know how to display the year that matches the sore.

expected output:

> Enter the number of years: 5
>
> Enter the starting year: 1999
>
> Enter stat for year 1999: 4
>
> Enter stat for year 2000: 7
>
> Enter stat for year 2001: 8
>
> Enter stat for year 2002: 10
>
> Enter stat for year 2003: 6
>
> Best stat was 10 in year 2002
>
> Worst stat was 4 in year 1999

my output:

> Enter the number of years: 5
>
> Enter the starting year: 1999
>
> Enter stat for year 1999: 4
>
> Enter stat for year 2000: 7
>
> Enter stat for year 2001: 8
>
> Enter stat for year 2002: 10
>
> Enter stat for year 2003: 6
>
> Best stat was 10 in year 2004

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5A {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
        int nubyear = sc.nextInt();

        int years [] = new int[nubyear];

        int i;
        int j;
        int h;
        int startyear = 0;
        int large =years[0];
        int yearcountr=0;


        System.out.print("Enter the starting year: ");
        startyear = sc.nextInt();

        for (i=0; i<nubyear; i++){
             years[i] = startyear++;
            System.out.print("Enter stat for year "+years[i]+": ");
             years[i] = sc.nextInt();
             if (large < years[i]){
                large = years[i];
                years[i] = startyear;
             }
            }
        System.out.print("Best stat was "+large+" in year "+startyear );
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an array if you don't intend to retrieve all the values entered by the user. You can just do the comparison for highest values as and when the user enters each value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
        int nubyear = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the starting year: ");
        int startyear = sc.nextInt();

        int highYear = 0; //variable to hold the year with the highest stat
        int highStat = 0; //variable to hold the current highest stat
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nubyear; i++) { 
            int tempYear = startyear++; //Hold the current year value until the comparison is done.
            System.out.print("Enter stat for year " + tempYear + ": ");
            int tempStat = sc.nextInt(); // Hold the current year stat until the comparison is done.
            if (highStat < tempStat) { //If the value entered is higher than the previous one, save the year and stat.
                highYear = tempYear;
                highStat = tempStat;
            }
        }       
        System.out.print("Best stat was " + highStat + " in year " + highYear);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YearDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfYrs = 0, startYrs = 0,statInput = 0,count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
        numOfYrs = sc.nextInt();
        int years[] = new int[numOfYrs];
        int stat[] = new int[numOfYrs];
        
        System.out.println("Enter the starting year: ");
        startYrs = sc.nextInt();
        
        while (numOfYrs != 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter stat for year: " + startYrs);
            statInput = sc.nextInt();
            years[count] = startYrs++;
            stat[count++] = statInput;
            numOfYrs--;
        }
        
        int largest = -(Integer.MAX_VALUE),smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE,bestYear = 0,worstYear = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
            if(largest < stat[i]) {
                largest = stat[i];
                bestYear = years[i];
            }
            if(smallest > stat[i]) {
                smallest = stat[i];
                worstYear = years[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Best Year: " + largest + " in year " + bestYear);
        System.out.println("Worst Year: " + smallest + " in year " + worstYear);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like this :

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
    int nubyear = sc.nextInt();

    int years [] = new int[nubyear];

    int i;
    int j;
    int h;
    int startyear = 0;
    int large =years[0];
    int yearcountr=0;
    int largest_year = 0 ;

    System.out.print("Enter the starting year: ");
    startyear = sc.nextInt();

    for (i=0; i<nubyear; i++){
         years[i] = startyear;
        System.out.print("Enter stat for year "+years[i]+": ");
         years[i] = sc.nextInt();
         if (large < years[i]){
            large = years[i];
            largest_year = startyear ;
         }
         startyear ++ ;
        }
    System.out.print("Best stat was "+large+" in year "+largest_year );
    }

}
```